# attempting to get main.cpp output using the makefile command make

Tags: makefile

g++: error: main: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:2: main] Error 1

this is my make file

main: main.cpp
g++ main -o main.cpp

main.o:
g++ -c main.cpp
PHONY: clean
clean:
rm * .o main.cpp

Comment: Please edit your question using StackOverflow's formatting facilities, so we can accurately see your makefile.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a makefile question.  This is because you need to learn how to invoke your compiler and what options it takes.  You can find documentation on how to invoke GCC here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC

A compiler like GCC will write its output to a file specified by the `-o` option.  The way options work is first you provide the option, then you provide the argument to the option.  You can't just muddle up all the options on the command line in a random order.

You have:

```
g++ main -o main.cpp
```

By putting `main.cpp` after the `-o` option you're telling GCC that the *output* file should be named `main.cpp` which is clearly not right.

You want your compile line to be this:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp
```

Since you're compiling the source file here, the other rule (to build `main.o`) is useless.

Also you want to list `main.cpp` as a prerequisite of `main`, otherwise make won't know that it needs to recreate `main` when `main.cpp` is modified:

```
main: main.cpp
        gcc -o main main.cpp
```